# Django CORS X-FirePHP-Version

Tags: python, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I am getting the following error message when I try to access my endpoints.

```
Request header field X-FirePHP-Version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

This is how my settings.py file looks

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'django_server',
    'corsheaders',  # For Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have additional headers that are going to be in your requests to a CORS enabled server, you should specify those in the `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` [django-cors](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) setting. This should solve it, but I would double check to make sure those headers are supposed to be there.

```
# In your project's settings.py

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-firephp-version',  # Added to default list
)

# more settings...
```

Under the hood this simply sets the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header on your server's responses.